# Youtube APIs- Videos search and results on my website

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube, youtube-api

I am new to this. I want to design a web page that must have a search bar which on submit retrieve results of youtube videos. I have seen similar question on stackoverflow bt I want to prepare it from scratch. **I am not asking for a code**. I just need some experienced person to direct me what all steps to be taken for making this project. I have also activated YouTube Analytics API YouTube Data API v3 and Freebase API  and even OAuth client with ID as a start for this project. Someone plz throw some lit on how to go abt it. What all things to be done? Or any links which will help me 2 understand this whole conecept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use YouTube Data API. Use list method - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Scroll down the page and you will see language specific examples.

There client libraries for different languages.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries

You need to prepare your search URL. In query parameter you will provide all the parts etc. You also will need to provide your Key.

If you do not want to use libraries then just scroll down the first link it has a API test utility. Submit your request after reading about all the parameters and you can see the created URL and result too.

I have implemented it using Python and I also used client library. I would recommend you to use client library as it will reduce lot of efforts and they are well tested too :)